# Region datatype in DNN User Profile not working properly

Tags: .net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I am using DNN Version: 7.4.1 
I have added two new fields in User Profile. Data type for these two user profiles are Country and Region (built-in data types). I do not have multiple fields in user profile with these data types. Both these fields are marked are Required and Visible.
At the time of Registering new user when user press update after providing all information (including country and region), User gets a validation error asking user to select Region. Region was selected but as soon as user clicks update button, selected Region included other items from dropdown just vanish and system gives validation error.
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been reported here: https://dnntracker.atlassian.net/browse/DNN-7063

You should add a comment and watch the issue to encourage DNN to fix it.

You can sort of work around it by not requiring a valid profile during registration or by not requiring Region.